# How to use Like '%' in a phrase with multiple words

Tags: sql, regex, hive

Let's say i have the following table

```
user|text
1   |red 123 orange blue green
2   |red orange blue
3   |blue orange 123 red
```

If I wanted to pull all users whose text includes both '123' and 'blue', how would i do it? I would want to pull user 1 and 3.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE text LIKE '%123%'&&'%blue%'
OR text LIKE '%blue%'&&'%123%'
```

Is this better solved thru using a regexp function?

Answer (score 1):

You need to repeat `LIKE` for each pattern.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE text LIKE '%123%' AND text LIKE '%blue%'
```

You could also write it as:

```
WHERE text LIKE '%123%blue%' OR text LIKE '%blue%123%'
```

or:

```
WHERE text RLIKE '123.*blue|blue.*123'
```

However, these two solutions get exponentially large if you have to match several strings in any order. The first version is linear in the number of matches.

Comment: `&&`? Shouldn't that be `AND`?

Comment: Some SQL dialects also have `&&`.

Comment: @barmar, what sub-versions of SQL has &&?

Comment: Gee!! I actually didnt knew that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE text LIKE '%123%'
and text like '%blue%'
```